# Why is my custom hook not re-initialised on path change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am using **ReactRouter** to route the application (**BrowserRouter** at the top level) with a **Switch** that includes all the routes.
In my use-case I want to be able to handle paths that include the path-parameters (`bedId`) and navigate between different sub-paths (i.e. `/beds/:bedId/`, `/beds/:bedId/info/`) as well asa case where the path is (`/beds/-`).
I also want to be able to direct user to a different "bed" while they are already on some bed, so `/beds/bed1/info` -> `/beds/bed2`, and so on...

My **BedView** component is responsible for routing within that `/beds/:bedId` path like so:

```js
// App.jsx (fragment)

<Switch>
  <Route
    path="/"
    exact
    render={() => (<Redirect to="/beds/-"/>)}
  />
  <Route
    path="/beds/-"
    exact
    component={SomeOtherComponent}
  />
  <Route
    path="/beds/:bedId"
    component={BedView}
  />
</Switch>
```

The problem occurs when I try to use a hook that relies on the current path-parameter to fetch the latest data (i.e. call to `/beds/bed1` will result in a call to `http://myapi.com/beds/bed1/timeseries`). The `useLatestData` hook is called from the BedView component, which look like so:

````js
// BedView.jsx (fragment)

export default function BedView(props) {
  const {bedId} = props.match.params;
  let {path, url} = useRouteMatch('/beds/:bedId');

  const bedData = useLatestData({
    path: `/beds/${bedId}/timeseries`,
    checksumPath: `/checksum/timeseries`,
    refresh: false
  });```


  if(!bedData){
    return <Loading/>;
  }

  return (
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path={path}>
         <Redirect to={`${url}/info`}/>
       </Route>
      <Route exact path={`${path}/info`} >
        <SomeComponent info={bedData.info} />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
}
````

...and the **useLatestData** hook is available [here](https://gist.github.com/marceliwac/cfa0705de7db0bb44901fcf48430720c).

The problem is the fact that upon redirecting from `/beds/bed1/info` to `/beds/bed2/info`, the hook does not update its props, even though the BedView component seems to be re-rendering. I have created a [version of the hook that 'patches' the problem](https://gist.github.com/marceliwac/0141d7c13650747c9e1ca8ab6625331c) by adding an **useEffect** hook in my custom hook, to detect the change in path (as supplied in the function arguments) and set data to null, but then the behaviour changes on the **BedView.jsx**'s end - making the following check fail:

```js
  if(!bedData){
    return <Loading/>;
  }
```

I'm not entirely sure which part is the culprit here and any guidance would be much appreciated! As far as I'm aware, the hook is no re-initialised because the path change still results in the same component. There is also one caveat, once I change the **BrowserRouter** to include the `forceRefresh` flag, everything works fine. Naturally, I don't want my page to refresh with every redirect though...

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle ?

Comment: I will try to create the repository that isolates the issue. JSFiddle might be a bit challenging to build this in and have a great observability of the path changes.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const {bedId} = props.match.params;
let {path, url} = props.match;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. After pressing the link to `/beds/bed2` (from page at `/beds/bed1`) the path in the address bar updates, but the **useLatestData** hook does not re-initialise and no request to `http://myapi.com/beds/bed2` is made.